# Does obsidian actually attract mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I read in a [book (Minecraft Ultimate Book Of Secrets)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/150310902X), on page 71, the following statement:

> Obsidian actually attracts mobs

I didn't believe this. I tried to Google it, investigating several wikis and forums to find an answer. I can't find anything saying whether obsidian does or does not attract mobs.

Does obsidian attract mobs?

Comment: The book seems like it isn't official, so I'd recommend taking everything in that book with a pinch of salt.

Comment: @arda that's why I tried to look it up, but I found absolutely nothing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not going to find anything saying it *doesn't*, simply because you could make an article infinitely long listing the things it doesn't do. That being said, no, obsidian, and every other block for that matter, doesn't attract mobs. Monsters can spawn on obsidian if it's dark enough, but it isn't any more likely than any other block.

Comment: *and every other block for that matter* - that isn't accurate.  See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/285850/101016.

Comment: @camelCase I wouldn't call that attracting, since there are no blocks that raise or decrease the chance of a particular mob spawning. It's either possible, or it isn't, there is no in between. The exception however is light level. It is true that monsters will spawn at light level 7 and lower, but it's more likely for lower light levels. All of this really strains the definition of "attract" though, since there is no AI leading mobs to a particular block.

Comment: @Daffy The chance of spawning is not affected, but the 'wandering' AI is definitely affected by the type of nearby blocks, so some mobs will tend to gravitate to certain types of blocks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm 99% sure that the book you read isn't official. Blocks don't attract mobs.

Comment: Do you have any sources to confirm that blocks don't attract mobs?

Comment: @Jaketr00 Last time I looked at the code, there was no such thing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie you might want to look at the Wandering AI again - block type and light level do influence it.

Comment: @Kcats I know darkness (which isn't a block) attracts hostile mobs. What sort of blocks attract general mobs?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/285850/101016.

Comment: They should add a block like a meat block to attract zombies. Also don't some blocks attract endermen?

Answer (score 4):

It is true that obsidian doesn't attract mobs, but the general statement that blocks don't attract mobs is not completely true. While mobs are wandering randomly, some destination blocks can be selected with higher probability than others.

Specifically:

- Hostile mobs are attracted to darkness
- Passive mobs are attracted to light
- Silverfish are attracted to Stone blocks
- Guardians are attracted to Water blocks
- Passive mobs are attracted to Grass blocks
- [unconfirmed] with fixing issue [MC-103339](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-103339) in snapshot 16w38a (1.11) Mooshrooms are attracted to Mycelium

Comment: This answer also suggests there is an attraction towards certain blocks: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89746/are-animals-attracted-to-light

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by the statement.  Does it suggest mobs spawn near obsidian, or that once spawned do mobs favour moving towards obsidian?  In both cases, here are my own observations from playing over the past few years:

I tend to find obsidian naturally where lava and water meet.  In an underground cave system the light from the lava appears to stop mobs spawning directly near the lava/water boundary.  Furthermore, I have never witnessed mobs willingly move to group up on the obsidian.  This would suggest that mobs are not attracted to obsidian (either through spawning or moving).

I only place obsidian to create nether portals.  In this case I have noticed zombie pigmen spawning regularly in the overworld.  I haven't really noticed the same in the nether (i.e. zombie pigmen just seem to spawn anywhere in the nether).

For a definitive answer I guess you could reverse engineer the spawn and movement code.  As you have already noticed, there is nothing really to suggest through other sites that obsidian attracts mobs.  I would be surprised if the book's statement turned out to be true.

Answer (score -2):

I built 2 castles in Minecraft (one for my fiancée and one for myself) mine is made from obsidian and my the other is pink concrete. Other than that one difference they are exactly identical, they both have the same amount of lighting in the same places yet my castle spawns mobs inside and my fiancée's castle doesn't, with that in mind I believe obsidian does cause mobs to spawn close by.

Answer (score -4):

No it does not because then nether portals would attract mobs.

Comment: But Nether portals *do* “attract” mobs (in the Overworld, they spawn zombie pigmen). Right answer for the wrong reason.

Comment: This is one of the posts I don't know what to do with in the LQP review queue.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek It's a genuine attempt at answering the question, even if it's completely wrong. As such, it shouldn't be deleted.